# xunit skip tests if other tests failed

Tags: c#, xunit

The problem:  I have a bunch of xunit tests that connect to an external server.  If that server is up - they fly through very quickly.  If that server is down, everything goes into timeouts and retries and the tests all take a *long* time.   The thing is, if I have 100 tests - if the first one fails, I still want all the rest to fail, but it's completely pointless running them...   What I'd like is to be able to make my own fact attribute something like:

```cs
   [FactInFailureGroup( "ConectsToBlah", typeof(ConnectionException)]
   public void TestOne()
   {
      ...
   }

   [FactInFailureGroup( "ConnectsToBlah", typeof(ConnectionException)]
   public void TestTwo()
   {
        ...
   }
```

I've looked at before/after attributes, but they don't seem to be able to kill the test or see the result - and I've looked at creating my own fact attribute, which looks like it can prevent the test from running, but not put in a trap for the result.   I really want to somehow make code along these lines:

```cs
   class FactInFailureGroupAttribute : FactAttribute
   {
        private static _failedGroups = new HashSet<String>();

         ...

        void BeforeTest( TestManipulator manipulator )
        {
            if (_failedGroups.contains( _thisGroup ))
                manipulator.SkipWithMessage( f"all tests in group {_thisGroup} failed because of {_exceptionType}");
        }

        void AfterTest( TestResult test )
        {
            if (test.Failed && test.Exception.GetType() == _exceptionType)
               _failedGroups.add( _thisGroup );
        }
   }
```

Comment: IMHO add a test fixture to share state between tests and perform a single noop api call.

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse constructors and statics to accomplish your task.

The constructor of your test class will get called at the beginning of every test but your static should exist for your entire test run.

Try something like this:

```
private static object Lock = new object();
private static bool? IsServerUp;

public FactAssertionTests()
{
  lock (Lock)
  {
    if (!IsServerUp.HasValue)
    {
      // check server connection and set IsServerUp
    }
    else if (!IsServerUp.Value)
    {
      throw new Exception("Failed to connect to server");
    }
  }
}
```

That way whatever test gets into the `Lock` first will check the server's up-ness.  If it fails, every test coming in next will throw the exception.

This isn't quite a decorator attribute and requires you to put all the tests into one class, but it's simple.

**Edit:**
I tested the following approach, it relies on the fact that xUnit runs all tests in a single class in serial.  If you've got tests spanning multiple classes this won't work:

```
public class ConnectionTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        RunServerTest(() =>
        {
            var svc = new ServiceConnection();
            svc.Connect();
        });
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        RunServerTest(() =>
        {
            var svc = new ServiceConnection();
            svc.Connect();
        });
    }

    private static bool? ServerIsDown;
    public void RunServerTest(Action testAction)
    {
        var exception = new Exception("Server is down, test will not run.");
        if (ServerIsDown.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            throw exception;
        }

        try
        {
            testAction.Invoke();
        }
        catch (ServerMissingException ex)
        {
            ServerIsDown = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that "check server connection and set isserverup"  -   it's quite a lot of code and effort - which is done transitively in the various tests - so basically I will know _after the first test_, and want to set the result from that

Comment: Edited, I couldn't seem to find a way to embed the try/catch into an attribute correctly so I gave a shot at wrapping it in an action executor function that can fail-fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by calling your first test explicitly in the constructor of the class. If it fails due to server missing it should throw an exception. This will prevent the class from being instantiated, and none of the other tests in the class will run. They will be marked as failed in the test explorer.

```
    public class SO74607887Tests
    {
        public SO74607887Tests()
        {
            TestOne();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestOne()
        {
            // Arrange
            // Act
            // Oops server is down
            throw new Exception("Server is down");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestTwo()
        {
            // Will not run
        }
    }
```

If your tests are distributed over a lot of different classes, you can follow @JeremyLakeman 's suggestion to use a fixture. Proceed as follows:

```
using System;
using Xunit;


namespace SO74607887_XunitCancelTestsIfOneFails
{

    // This class will never actually be instantiated, it is only present to provide information to Xunit.
    [CollectionDefinition("SO74607887")]
    public class SO74607887CollectionDefinition : ICollectionFixture<SO74607887Base>
    {
    }

    // This class creates a single object injected into the constructors of all the other classes in the collection.
    public class SO74607887Base : IDisposable
    {
        public bool serverOK;
        public SO74607887Base()
        {
            // Check server, if it is missing, set the flag
            serverOK = false;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Clean up
        }
    }

    [Collection("SO74607887")]
    public class SO74607887Tests
    {
        public SO74607887Tests(SO74607887Base basis)
        {
            if (!basis.serverOK)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Server is down, tests in {nameof(SO74607887Tests)} will not run.");
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestOne()
        {
            // Arrange
            // Act
            // Assert
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestTwo()
        {
            // Arrange
            // Act
            // Assert
        }
    }
}
```

The check on the server is only done once in the fixture. All the other classes only need to check if it is available. The fixture constructor is guaranteed to run before the test classes are instantiated.

Instead of a boolean to check, you could also simply make a method `checkServer(string forClass)` in the fixture class to call which itself throws the exception, then you'd only have to call

```
     basis.checkServer(nameof(SO74607887Tests));
```

in the test classes instead of throwing in each test class.

All the tests in the classes will be marked as failed in the Test Excplorer window:

[image]